# How do I write this code using SubSonic?

Tags: stored-procedures, ado.net, subsonic

I have some legacy code that I'm rewriting using SubSonic to help the future maintainers. For the most part it's been relatively simple, as everything makes a stored procedure call. But now I'm having some difficulty with some tightly-coupled ADO.NET code.

The code depends on the SqlDataAdapter to decide when to call an INSERT or UPDATE stored proc, which I understand. How can I rewrite this code in a SubSonic way?

```
public void SaveInvoice(InvoiceItems invoiceItems)
{
    // extraneous code removed
    // invoiceItems is a dataset

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "InvoiceItem_INSERT";
    cmd.Connection = conn;

    updateCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    updateCmd.CommandText = "InvoiceItem_UPDATE";
    updateCmd.Connection = conn;

    SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(cmd);
    SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(updateCmd);

    adapter.InsertCommand = cmd;
    adapter.UpdateCommand = updateCmd;

    adapter.Update(invoiceItems._InvoiceItemTable);
}
```

I'm new to SubSonic, so any help is appreciated. All helpful answers will be gleefully upvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't going to be an exact representation of that kind of code using SubSonic because the automagic insert/update is done specifically by the `SqlDataAdapter.Update()` method. If there somehow is, buried somewhere within the SubSonic namespace, I would also like to know how to use it!

If you're dealing with one table (e.g. `InvoiceItems`), you can do the test yourself (this uses SubSonic's automatically generated active record implementation):

```
int key = InvoiceItems.ID; // not sure what your primary key identifier is called
InvoiceItem item = new InvoiceItem(key);
if (item != null)
{
    SPs.InvoiceItem_UPDATE(param1, param2, etc).Execute();
}
else 
{
    SPs.InvoiceItem_INSERT(param1, param2, etc).Execute();
}
```

Hopefully this gets you started.

As a totally unrelated sidenote, [don't rely on the `DeepSave()` method](http://forums.subsonicproject.com/forums/t/4249.aspx) to try to save across multiple tables, because it is not implemented. I found that out the hard way...

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to get a Command object from the stored proc? SubSonic doco is so lacking. :(

Comment: I believe the best you can do is get SubSonic's version of the command object, SPs.StoredProcName().Command - I don't know if that will be helpful or not

Comment: I've been looking at that, but every time I try to use it I get an exception. I'm trying to decide if this is worth fighting for, or if I should just leave this code as it is. :/

Comment: Yeah, especially since it already works and it seems pretty straightforward I see no reason for an overhaul unless you're completely moving to SubSonic